# TwinCAT XAR showing file missing error on starting windows PC

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

The windows-PC having TwinCAT XAR installed on it, after starting shows a file missing error. I tried reinstalling with the fresh download. But, the same error appeared again.
The error is shown in the picture
[image: File missing error]

The system information is also shared in the below image. To check the compatibility of the system with TwinCAT XAR.
[image: System information]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is caused by mfc140u.dll not being available in System32.

Try copying mfc140u.dll from System32 on your own developer PC to System32 on the PC. This has resolved the issue for my colleague .